# Run a "PUT" request using Rest-Api on Azure DevOps

Tags: postman, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to run a PUT request using Postman to change the retention rules of a specific build definition, in Azure DevOps, and change the *daysToKeep* value.

[image]

But I keep getting the error:
*"The request specifies pipeline ID 1722 but the supplied pipeline has ID 0."*

**Any idea where do I go wrong?**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In order to change\update any parameter on the build definition, first run a **GET** request.
The result **JSON** output should be used as the body for the **PUT** request.
Use this body and change\update the relevant parameter(s) you need...
It is very important to increase the "**revision**" parameter, located in the root of the JSON output, in 1. (for example, if current is 97, for next run it should be 98).

Special thanks to **Tinxuanna** for directing me to this solution!

Answer (score 0):

@ShaiO Please take a look at this link [List pipelines Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/pipelines/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0). It may help you because it gets a list of the pipelines.

Then you can create a pipeline following the documentation.

Comment: Hi,
I'm looking for a way to change the retention of an existing build definition.

Comment: Try to use `build-release/Build/1722` in the uri.

Comment: nope :-( , I got 404 Not Found

Comment: Please give it a try with: `PUT https://dev.azure.com/<myOrg>/<myProject>/_apis/pipelines/1722/runs?api-version=6.0-preview.1`. Instead of build/definitions use pipelines.

Comment: "Message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'PUT'."

Comment: Let's try method 'POST' and see if everything is ok. Sorry for many answers, but I search and try to help you.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, will try anything.
The last run using "POST" I got:
*"message": "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: definition.Repository"*

Comment: I think I'm missing something in the request. The request definition is: *PUT https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}?secretsSourceDefinitionId={secretsSourceDefinitionId}&secretsSourceDefinitionRevision={secretsSourceDefinitionRevision}&api-version=6.0*.

So I guess it has to be something with *secretsSourceDefinitionId={secretsSourceDefinitionId}*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243376/discussion-between-tinxuanna-and-shaio).